# Android: Parse JSON from url

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Here is the url [JSON](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XbGs_qK2PQA?v=2&alt=jsonc)

I want to parse the JSON and get `title` from the link and store it to a String.

I have tried other JSON parsing examples but everytime I try those, it either doesn't work or my app crashes.

Code -

```
//the components are in separate methods
web = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    protocol = "https://www.youtube.com/";
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();  
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web.loadUrl(protocol);

    web.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
            Request request = new Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download"); 
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);        

        }
    });
//Adding download manager to it. Download manager downloads the youtube video but the title is changed.

//I have action bar button, on click of which the download url of current weburl, converts it into mp3 and redirects user to the download page.

case R.id.action_download:

        String aJsonString = "ffff";

        final String webUrl = web.getUrl();
        String z = webUrl.substring(30);

        protocol = "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/?e=session_expired&t#v=" + z;
        web.loadUrl(protocol);

        String json = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + z + "?v=2&alt=jsonc";

        getData();
//calling your method           

        return true;

//your method

public void getData()
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XbGs_qK2PQA?v=2&alt=jsonc");

    try
    {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    String _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(_response);
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
    String tile = data.getString("title");

    Toast.makeText(this, tile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Comment: refer http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: post the crashing code. If you include the code and stacktrace will help solve your proble. you haven't posted anything

Comment: I will but plz tell me how to convert JSON in that url to string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json

```
{ // json object node 
    "apiVersion": "2.1",
    "data": {  // json object data
        "id": "XbGs_qK2PQA",
        "uploaded": "2013-11-27T16:50:00.000Z",
        "updated": "2014-08-15T12:08:36.000Z",
        "uploader": "eminemvevo",
        "category": "Music",
        "title": "Eminem - Rap God (Explicit)", // your title key value pair
```

To get title

```
JSONOBject json = new JSONOBject("json string");
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
String title = data.getString("title");
```

You can consider using google gson also

> How to convert JSON in that url to string?

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getData();
    return null;
}
}
```

Your getData

```
public void getData()
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XbGs_qK2PQA?v=2&alt=jsonc");

    try
    {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 

    JSONOBject json = new JSONOBject(_response);
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
    String tile = data.getString("title");

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

To invoke

```
new TheTask().execute();
```

Comment: How to convert JSON in that url to string?

Comment: @ASG you need to make a http request to the server and retrieve the json frst. You need to post what you have done for further help

Comment: @ASG check the edit. i hope you know how to invoke asynctask atleast

Comment: Is there any other simpler way to do it? I just want to download a youtube video preserving it's title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59407/discussion-between-asg-and-raghunandan).

Comment: @ASG depends on what you want and whether you want to use external libraries like retrofit google gson..